# How to prevent SQL injection while executing a MySQL statement through shell?

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, sql-injection

I have this code:

```
printf '%s' 'Enter deployment request ID: '
read request_id
[[ $request_id ]] || { printf '%s' 'Request ID is required' >&2; exit 2; }
...
mysql -h "$db_host" -u app_user --database dep_db -p -sNE "
    update dep_requests set
      state='FAILED', end_time=sysdate(), message='Cancelled manually'
    where id='$request_id' limit 1;
"
```

Since `request_id`, which is a string, is received as a user input, it could possibly lead to SQL injection.  What is the best way to make this code free from that vulnerability?

I can possibly validate the input with a regex match.  Are there better ways?

Comment: Not mysql, but this could provide some clues: http://caryrobbins.com/dev/postgres-scripting/

Comment: A regex match seems a valid approach.

Comment: How about force converting the value of `request_id` to integer? 
`request_id=$(($request_id + 0))` .
It could help for numbers, but no for other types (such as strings).

Comment: IMHO you would better to rewrite it with python...

Comment: a variable need two passes of escaping, first pass to make it a safe mysql value, the second pass to be bash command line safe. `printf '%q'` could be used for the second, but I dont think there is a sane solution for the first, because of locale.

Comment: if your input is an integer, filter with regex is more feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Some people propose to do this using [SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-variable.html) syntax:

```sql
SET @requestId = '$request_id';
update dep_requests set
  state='FAILED', end_time=sysdate(),
  message='Cancelled manually'
where id=@request_id limit 1;
```

The `$request_id` is a reference to your bash variable. If you paste this into a double quoted bash string, it ought to work.

Since we are still pasting string together: If you escape single quotes with `\'` in `$request_id`, I *think* an attacker can't escape that. E.g.: `request_id="${request_id//\'/\\\'}"`